# I want to use some specific chrome profile in python-selenium but I got an error

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, browser-automation

Here's my code

When I run my code it opens that mentioned profile but it didn't execute the rest of the code. Please help me solve this problem.

and I found this error **DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist**. so now what should i do for that
Thank You.

I've encountered a challenge while running my Python Selenium script. The script successfully opens the specified Chrome profile but fails to execute the subsequent code. In the console output, I've identified the error message: "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist."

```
class CustomWebDriver(WebDriver):
    def __init__(
        self, headless=True, is_eager=False, disable_images=False, is_none=False
    ):
        options = ChromeOptions()
        user_data_directory = "C:\\Users\\{username}\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data"
        options.binary_location = "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
        options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={user_data_directory}")
        options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Profile 3') 
        options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
```

```
Opening in existing browser session.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\TOC\test\main.py", line 35, in <module>
    driver = CustomWebDriver(headless=False)
  File "D:\TOC\test\driver.py", line 59, in __init__
    super().__init__(service=service, options=options)
  File "D:\TOC\test\.venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "D:\TOC\test\.venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "D:\TOC\test\.venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 208, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "D:\TOC\test\.venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 292, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "D:\TOC\test\.venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\TOC\test\.venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7D93C82B2+55298]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D9335E02]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D91F05AB]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D921DCD8]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D921B30E]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D925A198]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D9259CB0]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D9251E83]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D922670A]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D9227964]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7D9740AAB+3694587]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7D979728E+4048862]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7D978F173+4015811]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7D94647D6+695590]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D9340CE8]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D933CF34]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D933D062]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D932D3A3]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFE7717257D+29]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFE77CAAA58+40]
```

Comment: You should include your driver initialization code.  The error you are getting suggests that the path to the binary is wrong, or one of your options is causing it to crash on startup.